# The name <control name> does not exist in the current context inline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having an issue where I am doing a foreach inline on my default.aspx and I am getting “does not exist in the current context” error for the collections list lst that I have created in my code behind. I’m not sure what’s missing. 
I can see controls from my code behind so I know page_load is firing.

Should I see lst in my designer? I am not 100% positive if it not being generated properly is the cause. I added a test literal and that was added. I compiled my project in both debug and runtime. Then I added my inline for each after the build as well.

- Namespace matches
- Autoevent is set to true
- put in !Page.IsPostback

I can loop through lst and append the values to a literal and see the values coming through.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/WebSite.master"     CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin._Default" AutoEventWireup="true"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<h2></h2>
<div>
    <% foreach (Services service in lst)
       {  %>

    <% } %>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrl_ServiceList" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Security.Principal;
using RecycleAdmin.Utilities;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Admin
{

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Create my properties

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        getListOfClosuresFollowups();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = getTable();
            List<Services> lst = dt.ToCollection<Services>();

            foreach (Services service in lst)
            {
                ltrl_ServiceList.Text += service.service_nm.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'lst' appears to be a local variable in Page_Load and is not a property of the page itself.

Comment: `lst` is a local variable you must declare it as instance level member.

Comment: Your method of using a for loop is more similar to Razor Syntax, but ASP.NET Web Forms uses the [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you've created a local variable called `lst` but how the server markup can be aware about its existence???

At least, you'll need to declare it as a `protected` class field or property and it will be accessible by the markup part of your page:

```
class .... 
{
    protected List<Services> lst;
}
```

BTW, it's sad that you need to do a `for` loop there: [take a look at `Repeater` control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Matias for the help and the answer. I am not using the repeater control or any control on purpose. I want to get a better understanding of using lists and generics and not just bind my dataset to a control and let it do all the work for me. I learned something today with this issue that I would not have if I just plopped in a repeater.

Comment: @user2316023 No problem! If you're just learning, it's ok. Otherwise, using ASP.NET like ASP Classic would be an epic fail.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers/comments here, I agree you will be needing to define your variable. What I might add is that you have its value stored in the page's viewstate. This can even be done in conjunction with a master page to securely persist variables across multiple content pages. I'm a VB.net programmer, but here is some sample MSDN code or [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for more information.

**To store a property in the viewstate:**

```
public String Text
        {
            get 
            { 
                object o = ViewState["Text"]; 
                return (o == null)? String.Empty : (string)o;
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }
```

---

Here is another helpful link I found: [MSDN How to: Save Values in View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)